# Show that $\mathbb{P}(\exp(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i) >1)\to\frac{1}{2}$ for $X_i\in L^2$ i.i.d. with zero mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots\in L^2$ be i.i.d. random variables with $E(X_i)=0$. Show that $$\mathbb{P}\left(\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right) >1\right)\to\frac{1}{2}$$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

---

**My approach:**

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right) >1\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i > 0\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i > 0\right)$$

From the law of large numbers, we know that $\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i\to 0$ in probability, i.e.

$$\forall\epsilon>0: \mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right|>\epsilon\right)\to 0$$

I now want to make some kind of statement about $P\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i<0\right)$ in order to proceed with the proof. How do I continue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply CLT instead of SLLN. $P(\frac {S_n} {\sqrt n \sigma } >0) \to 1-\Phi (0)=\frac  1 2$ where $\Phi$ is the standard normal distribution. Hence $P(S_n >0) \to \frac  1 2$.